# Multidimensional Array PHP in CSS

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem in my web app.

I'd like to make a menu, when menu clicked it'll be active in css.

Code below is my index.php

```
<?php
    include 'menu.php';
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    switch ($page) {
      case 'endCart':
        include 'endCart.php';
        break;

      case 'trxLog':
        include 'invoice.php';
        break;

      case 'graph':
        include 'graph.php';
        break;

      case 'activeBasket':
        include 'activeBasket.php';
        break;

      case 'logout':
        include 'logout.php';
        break;

      default:
        include 'endCart.php';
        break;
    }

?>
```

And code below is menu.php

```
<div class="column" id="sidebar">
  <div class="ui secondary vertical fluid menu">

    <?php

    foreach($sidemenu as $arr){
      echo '<a class="item" href="'.$arr[1].'">'.$arr[0].'</a>';
    }

    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get variable `$sidemenu` from array with value below :

```
$sidemenu = array(
    array('End Cart','index.php?page=endCart', 'endCart'),
    array('Transaction Log','index.php?page=trxLog', 'trxLog'),
    array('Graph','index.php?page=graph', 'graph'),
    array('Active Basket','index.php?page=activeBasket', 'activeBasket')
);
```

As writen in file menu.php, there is tag <a> with `item` in its CSS class.

So my problem is when user clicked specific menu in that tag will append CSS class `active`.

#### Update!!

This problem has been solved, and here it is my update for menu.php. Big thanks for @Magnus and @Steve to help me solve this.

```
foreach($sidemenu as $arr){
  echo ($page == $arr[2]) ? "<a class=\"item active\" href=\"".$arr[1]."\">".$arr[0]."</a>" : "<a class=\"item\" href=\"".$arr[1]."\">".$arr[0]."</a>";
}
```

Comment: You need to do this in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Yea... you cannot do this in php...

Comment: can you give me some recommendation sources to solve that problem?

Comment: Use javascript. that needs to be done on the frontend. php has no idea what has been clicked... @acreativeless

Comment: If you want dynamically add the class, then javascript is what you will need (jQuery solves this quick). if you want to add the class on rendering, so you will detect in PHP the element you will need to add the class (based on URL for instance)

Comment: This can definitely be done in PHP since it looks like the page is reloaded on click. PHP has the menus listed and the current URL.

Comment: @Maxwells.c do you have some sources that i can do it?

Comment: thank you very much to all of you for your answers, i'll try it

Comment: If jquery, you will need to read the jQuery Documentation. if PHP, an IF inside your foreach will do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the order of the page and menu include. That way, `$page` will be available in your menu.php-file:

```
// I also added a check to see if that query string exists
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
include 'menu.php';
```

In your menu.php, just check if the loop is printing the current url:

```
foreach($sidemenu as $arr){
    echo '<a class="item ' . $arr[2] == $page ? "active" : null . '" href="'.$arr[1].'">'.$arr[0].'</a>';
}
```

This will give the current page link the class `active`.

#### Edit

I totally missed that `$arr[2]` already contains the page key. You don't need to build the url to compare it, as I did in my first example. Thanks @steve for pointing that out.

Comment: `$arr[2]` contains the page key, so you can remove the `$currentUrl` variable and simply check `$arr[2] == $page`.

Comment: @acreativeless Not working in what sense? If you check the source, does the current page link have a class called "active"? Have you styled the "active" class in your css?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience @MagnusEriksson, but I'd like to say that the result of your answer is looks like https://jsfiddle.net/hvu0bqza/2/

Comment: @Syarif - Double check that you implemented the current version. I did edit it a couple of times. The first couple of versions had invalid quoting. If you did, please show how you implemented it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Thank you very much, I've already checked it and I'll post my recent code then. But, might I update your answer?

Comment: @Syarif - Make an edit to your question and add the new info (keep the current content as is, though).